# optimize a date function for timeseries

Tags: python, function, dataframe, optimization, time-series

i have a dataset with Time(seconds) column, i want to creat another column with full date and time ( yy/mm/dd h:m:s), so i wrote the function below but it takes too long for larger datasets, any advice how can i optimize it ?

Column Time is like this

```
0     0.0
1     0.2
2     0.4
3     0.6
4     0.8
5     1.0
6     1.2
7     1.4
8     1.6
9     1.8
10    2.0
11    2.2
12    2.4
13    2.6
14    2.8
15    3.0
16    3.2
17    3.4
18    3.6
19    3.8
20    4.0
```

## function

````
def calcul_datetime(ds,h,m,s,Y,M,D):

    
    for index,row in ds.iterrows():
        
        
        if row.Time.is_integer()==True and row.Time!=0:
            
            s=s+1
            if s==60:
                
                m=m+1
                s=0
                if m==60:
                    h=h+1
                    m=0
                    if h==24:
                        D=D+1
                        h=0
        ds.iloc[index,9]="{Y}-{M}-{D} {heure}:{min}:{sec}".format(Y=Y, M=M, D=D ,heure=h,min=m,sec=s)
        
    return ds  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` module has pretty much everything you need to do computations on times and dates.

Specifically, the `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` method converts seconds [since the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to a `datetime.datetime` object.  This object then has a convenient method for string representation: `datetime.datetime.strftime`.

Here's an example:

```py
import datetime

some_arbitrary_time_value = 10000000
as_a_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(some_arbitrary_time_value)
as_a_string = as_a_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(as_a_string)
```

Comment: just want to add a remark :  my observations starts at 2019-04-01 4:35:8 ( that when sensors start collecting data) how can i use fromtimestamp ? because when i looked for it i've found that ```datetime.fromtimestamp``` gives you a naïve datetime corresponding to what local time for that POSIX (UTC) timestamp would be for you

Comment: Get a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for your start date, then.  It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but I assure you that `datetime`s are your ticket.